# Haskell confused by -> and => in a function

Tags: haskell

What is the are differences between `->` and `=>` ?
In the declaration of a function?

```
foobar :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
```

Comment: Would you have to modify the function to achieve what? In what way does the current definition of the function not work for you?

Comment: Show us the code that the `/` appears in.

Comment: That error message is not caused by any code contained in your question. `/` doesn't even appear in any of the code you've shown us. That said the problem (which is entirely unrelated to anything in your question) is that you're using `/` on an integer. `/` can only be used with fractionals (e.g. doubles). For integer division use the `div` function.

Comment: Why would you divide 1 by s (an operation which could not possibly have an integer result - and would always result in 0 using integer division) if you're trying to create a list of **integers**?

Comment: @sepp2k Hmm.. I didn't see that. I'll have to recheck a couple of things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`->` is for function takes. The signature `x -> y` means "a function that takes an `x` and returns a `y`".

`=>` is for dealing with classes. It can appear only once per type signature. The stuff to the left of it is a "context", listing which types must be instances of what classes. The stuff on the right is a normal type signature.

For example, `(Num x, Show y) => x -> y -> String` would indicate that `x` has to be a number type and `y` has to be a displayable type.

Answer (score 3):

Read about [Type Constraints](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types#Type_constraints).

Basically `foo :: (X a) => a -> b` means type `a` must have an instance of type class `X`.